# Gradle Build errors while running sample code on Android Studio Iguana

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to run a simple gitlab code project on Android Studio Iguana.
And I keep getting the following error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':PhotoLog_Start:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:143)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:402)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:389)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:382)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:368)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.MissingValueException: Cannot query the value of this property because it has no value available.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.get(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:748)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:491)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:404)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:357)
```

And Here is the Build.gradle file

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2022 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt"
}
android {
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.photolog.start"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
        freeCompilerArgs += ["-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn", "-Xjvm-default=enable"]
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha14'
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.6.0-alpha05'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.0"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.1.0"
    def room_version = "2.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.0-alpha02")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.0-alpha02")
    implementation("androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.0-alpha02")
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

Can someone please suggest what could be the solution for this?

I tried changing the **distributionUrl** to a few different options and that didnt seem to work.
I want to run the sample locally so I can practise some code here.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fix here [android-cache-fix-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/gradle/android-cache-fix-gradle-plugin/issues/432)

Update your plugin dependency to the newest version

```
plugins {
   id("org.gradle.android.cache-fix") version "3.0.1"
}
```

Using legacy plugin application:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
     maven {
       url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
     }
   }
 dependencies {
   classpath("gradle.plugin.org.gradle.android:android-cache-fix-gradle-plugin:3.0.1")
   }
 }

 apply(plugin = "org.gradle.android.cache-fix")
```

[org.gradle.android.cache-fix](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gradle.android.cache-fix)